# Python Flask data feed from Pandas Dataframe, dynamically define with unique endpoint

Tags: javascript, python, flask, web-deployment

Hi I am building a web app with Flask Python. I got a problem here:

```
@app.route('/analytics/signals/<ticker_url>')
def analytics_signals_com_page(ticker_url):
    all_ticker = full_list
    ticker_name = com_name
    ticker = ticker_url.upper()
    pricerec = sp500[ticker_url.upper()].tolist()
    timerec = sp500[ticker_url.upper()].index.tolist()
    return render_template('company.html', all_ticker=all_ticker, ticker_name=ticker_name, ticker=ticker, pricerec=pricerec, timerec=timerec)
```

Here I am defining company pages based on the  a page will contain different content. The problem is that everything is fine upto ticker = ticker_url.upper(). It works perfectly fine. But for pricerec and timerec, they make problems.

sp500 is a pandas DataFrame columns being companies like "AAPL", "GOOG","MSFT", and so forth 505 companies and the index are timestamps, and values are the prices at each time.

So what I am doing for the pricerec, I am taking the ticker_url and use it to take the specific company's price and make it as a list. And timerec is to take the index (timestamps) and make it as a list. And I am passing these two variables into the company.html page.

But it makes internal server error. I do not know why it happens. 
My expectation was that when a user click a button that href to "~/analytics/signals/aapl" then the company.html page will contain the pricerec and timerec for me to draw a graph. But it didn't work like that. It makes internal server error. I defined those two variables in the javascript also like I did for the other variables(all_ticker, ticker_name, and ticker)

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the exception you're getting? You should see a traceback on the terminal where you started the server.

Comment: I have solved this. Problem was that the sp500 pandas datafram dose not contain all the tickers in all_ticker.